# PHP return array from function not working properly

Tags: php, arrays, function, return

I have 2 phps, one containing the main code and another containing functions:

1. From PHP1 I call a function contained in PHP2 parsing a value: `$ubicacionlibre=listado($pasillo);`
2. Function `listado()` creates an array `$ubicacionlibre`. If I `var_dump($ubicacionlibre)` from the function it shows correctly the array with 233 items:
   `array(233) { [0]=> string(4) "5014" [1]=> string(4) "5015"...`

Then I use return_array($ubicacionlibre) to send this array back to PHP1

If I var_dump returned `$ubicacionlibre` from PHP1 it shows array as 1 item:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(233) { [0]=> string(4) "5014" [1]=> string(4) "5015"....
```

Then if I try to access the values contained in the array it shows "Array to string convertion" and I cannot use the array properly. May I use serialize/unserialize or what am I missing?

Comment: **I have 2 phps** means ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz - I'm guessing, 2 php files

Comment: You probably are doing some things wrong in your code, but without including the code we can't know what things you're doing wrong.

Comment: array to string conversion means you're trying to echo an array, you need to specify the element you want, like echo $myArr[0] rather than echo $myArr

Comment: How are you trying to access the values contained in the array? which function are you using?

Comment: What is *"return_array"*? If `$ubicacionlibre` is an array then you should just `return $ubicacionlibre;`. If you `return array($ubicacionlibre);` then you create a new array that contains a single element (`$ubicacionlibre`), i.e. a two-level array.

Comment: 2 phps means 2 php files, yes. To access the values in the array, if I use echo $ubicacionlibre[0] it shows "array" and if I use $ubicacionlibre[1] it shows error Undefined Offset. If I do the same in the function before retruning the array it shows the right values ($ubicacion[0]=5014; $ubicacion[1]=5015...It is like if when returning the array it converts it from array=10 values to array=1 value.

Comment: Means `You are accessing the array AS *string*`. Use index if you know the proper length.

Comment: Ok Axiac, you are right, I was converting the array $ubicacionlibre to a two level array with the command return_array, and I had to use only return. Now it is working, thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$ubicacionlibre` is an array then you should just `return $ubicacionlibre;`.

If you `return array($ubicacionlibre);` then you create a new array that contains a single element (`$ubicacionlibre`), i.e. a two-level array.